# WinSCP Disable ResumeSupport in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am using WinSCP to write to connect a SQL Server to an SFTP server. I am trying to write a file to an SFTP server where I only have write access, not modify. I am having a problem because I get back

> Cannot create remote file '/xxx.filepart'.

The documentation suggests this is because I do not have modify access to the target directory. I did this *WinSCP -> Preferences -> Endurance -> Disable*
I checked the `winscp.ini` file and `ResumeSupport` is `2` (I believe this means disabled). I ran `"echo $transferOptions.ResumeSupport"` and it says that it is in a default state.

I have checked this documentation:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_resume
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#resumesupport

However, I don't see a PowerShell example, just C#.

I have tried various permutations of `$transferOptions.ResumeSupport.State = Off`, `$transferOptions.ResumeSupport.Off`, and whatnot. One of these says that it's read-only.

I know `$transferOptions` is a variable here but it comes from the default script. The object determines transfer options  `$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions`

Thanks in advance for help

edit: The overall problem is I only have write access to the server, but not modify. I am getting a new error: "Cannot overwrite remote file '/xxx'.$$. It looks like the dollar signs are some sort of temp file that it's trying to create. Is there a way to disable whatever setting is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax for using an enumeration in PowerShell is described in
the article [Using WinSCP .NET assembly from PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#enums).

> Enumeration values are accessed using static field syntax `[Namespace.Type]::Member`, for example `[WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp`.

---

You can find a PowerShell example for [`TransferResumeSupport.State`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferresumesupport#state) in [Converting to .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#net) section of `get` and `put` command documentation:

```
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$transferOptions.ResumeSupport.State = [WinSCP.TransferResumeSupportState]::Off
$session.GetFiles(..., ..., $False, $transferOptions).Check()
```

---

[WinSCP GUI can also generate a code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) (including `TransferOptions` and `TransferResumeSupportState` code) for you.

Comment: Thank you Martin! WinSCP is amazing. I knew what I needed to have happen I just couldn't figure out how to articulate it.